# Don't render layout when calling from Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails action called index that renders the content for my page along with the layout. When I go to the /index action with a browser it works like expected. I want to be able to also render this action by calling it with Ajax, I am doing this using the following:

```
<%= link_to "Back", orders_path, :id => 'back_btn', :remote => true %>
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  jQuery("#back_btn").bind("ajax:complete", function(et, e){
    jQuery("#mybox").html(e.responseText);
  });
<% end %>
```

When the action is called this way I would like it to render and pass the index action back, excluding the layout. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to add a format.js action to your controller action like so:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
  format.html 
  format.json { render json: @foos }
```

Ideally, you would want to create a index.js.erb file that would build the contents of the page:

```
$('#foos_list').update("<%= escape_javascript(render(@foos)) %>");
```

If you're going to update the contents of a div, to basically update a whole page inside of a layout, then you're going to want to change it up a little bit.  Inside of the format.js, you can do this:

```
format.js { render 'foos/index', :layout => false }
```

But if you're trying to go with an ajaxified front-end, may I recommend a framework for doing this, like [Spine](http://spinejs.com/)?  It will go a long way in helping you build your site.

Also, using a framework like this will force you to separate your application per @Zepplock's second suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can just detect if the request is an XML HTTP Request, then render a blank layout like so:

```
render layout: 'blank' if request.xhr?
```

You'll need to create a blank layout in `app/views/layouts/blank.html.erb` like this:

```
<%= yield %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to let server know that there's a difference in request type. It can be done in several different ways:

- Append a key value to the URL (for example layout=off) and change your controller logic to render data with no view. This is kind of a hack.
- Make your controller return data via XML or JSON (controller will know what content type is being requested) then format it accordingly and present in browser. This is more preferred way since you have a clear separation between content types and is better suited for MVC architecture.
- Create an API that will serve data. This will lead to separate auth logic, more code on client side, additional APi controller(s) on server etc. Most likely an overkill for your case