# Ruby on Rails: output JSON data from array

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, xmlhttprequest

I have a webpage in which a javascript code requests JSON data from a remote URL using XMLHTTPRequest().
The URL is served by a Ruby on Rails app. I tried to print an hardcoded JSON string from a test view but it get wrapped around HTML tags (html, head, body etc..etc..) so it's not reconized as a valid JSON string from the javascript code. What I want is to output a raw JSON string straight from a Ruby object.

Comment: Maybe this would help: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render and this one: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: and this is another question like yours in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716552/dont-render-layout-when-calling-from-ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either use `respond_to` block (in case your action handles multiple formats) or explicitly state that you want to render json (easier in case your action only handles json):

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def some_action
    @data        = Data.find(1)
    @string_json = '{ "key": "value" }'

    render json: @data # render json: @string_json also works
  end
end
```

EDIT:

If you're trying to only render a json string on a page, you should disable a common layout for your action:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  layout 'application', :except => :some_action

  def some_action
    @json_string = ' .... '
  end
end
```

some_action.erb:

```
<%= @json_string %>
```

Comment: thank you. That's code must be in the controller, am I right?. What about the corresponding view erb? Maybe the .erb file is not required at all, just create the route on route.rb, ins't it?